# how can i fix this heroku auto deploy problem

Tags: heroku

```
2019-01-17T15:51:37.839972+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

2019-01-17T16:28:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ----@gmail.com

2019-01-17T16:28:39.087510+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting

2019-01-17T16:28:39.136023+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting

2019-01-17T16:28:38.767079+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 57def975 by user -----@gmail.com

2019-01-17T16:28:39.969586+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

2019-01-17T16:28:40.075330+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143

2019-01-17T16:28:41.459214+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`

2019-01-17T16:34:14.183572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=rsgad.herokuapp.com request_id=91be0535-127f-4363-8131-952b38632b22 fwd="81.206.233.213" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2019-01-17T16:34:14.480990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rsgad.herokuapp.com request_id=f75406ea-e29f-4d45-bfbc-ca5e116cb029 fwd="81.206.233.213" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: `code=H14 desc="No web processes running"` -> I would suggest: Give your app a dyno in the heroku UI

Comment: Great to hear. I added it as an answer, so if you like to accept :) :)

Answer (score 0):

`code=H14 desc="No web processes running?` -> I would suggest: Give your app a dyno in the heroku UI